# Archivos ocultos en el escritorio

Tags: cmd, terminal

A la hora de ejecutar el comando 'ls' en la terminal (sin importar si es la cmd, Hyper, etc) cuando me encuentro en el directorio de mi Desktop, aparecen un montón de archivos que en realidad no tengo ahí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado de todo y no los puedo sacar de ahí. Nisiquiera me aparecen como archivos ocultos...

Esto es lo que dice ls -la:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Son enlaces?  Que dice ls -la ?

Comment: Ya puedes ver lo que dice, lo acabo de editar :)

Answer (score 0):

con `rm -f  .*nombre_archivo*` deberia bastar.

El parametro `-f` fuerza el borrado.